# How to query for rows that have the different values for one column?

Tags: sql, t-sql

For an OrderLine table like this:

| Order | Line | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X | X |
| 1 | 2 | X | Y |
| 2 | 1 | Y | X |
| 2 | 2 | Y | X |
| 3 | 1 | X | Y |
| 3 | 2 | Y | Y |
| 4 | 1 | X | Y |
| 4 | 2 | X | Y |

Col4 can be either X or Y, not both. Order 1 in this table violates the rule. How do I find all orders that have different values in Col4 for the same Order?

My initial thought was joining into the table multiple times, then using a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[Order], A.Line, A.Col3, A.Col4, A.Col4
FROM OrderLines A 
   INNER JOIN OrderLines B ON B.[Order]= A.[Order]
      AND B.Line = A.Line
GROUP BY A.[Order], A.Line, A.Col3, A.Col4, A.Col4, B.[Order], B.Line, B.Col4
HAVING(A.Line <> B.Line AND A.Col4 <> B.Col4)
ORDER BY A.[Order] ASC, A.Line ASC
```

Comment: Obcono is Slovenian for municipality

Comment: Where is `OBCONO` in your table?

Comment: Does a not exist work? SELECT DISTINCT 
       A.[Order], 
       A.Line, 
    A.Col3, 
    A.Col4
  FROM OrderLines A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (
     SELECT 1
       FROM OrderLines B 
   WHERE A.[Order] = B.[Order]
     AND A.Col4 <> B.Col4
   );

Comment: @PM77-1 mistake on my part. Edited.

Comment: What is your expected result? Just a row that contains `1`?

Comment: @HABO the solution below gave me the result I expected. Looking for results where one column has differing values for the items grouped by the first column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find all orders that have different values in Col4 for the same Order

```
--Create OrderLine table
CREATE TABLE OrderLine 
(
    [Order]     VARCHAR(512),
    Line    VARCHAR(512),
    col3    VARCHAR(512),
    col4    VARCHAR(512)
);

--Populate OrderLine table
INSERT INTO OrderLine ([Order] , Line , col3 , col4) VALUES
    ('1 ', '1 ', 'X ', 'X'),
    ('1 ', '2 ', 'X ', 'Y'),
    ('2 ', '1 ', 'Y ', 'X'),
    ('2 ', '2 ', 'Y ', 'X'),
    ('3 ', '1 ', 'X ', 'Y'),
    ('3 ', '2 ', 'Y ', 'Y'),
    ('4 ', '1 ', 'X ', 'Y'),
    ('4 ', '2 ', 'X ', 'Y')

--Verify that the record were added correctly  
SELECT * FROM OrderLine

--Select all order rows that have differing col4 values  
SELECT * FROM OrderLine
WHERE [order]  in
(
    SELECT [order] 
    FROM OrderLine group by [order]
    HAVING min(col4)<>max(col4)
)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iZwdNl6A)

| Order | Line | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X | X |
| 1 | 2 | X | Y |